# Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function. Show that $f$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have been trying to prove this with some continuity theorems but haven't put together a good proof yet.

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? (There are at least two plausible ones, and they feature quite different proofs, at least on the surface.)

Comment: If $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, what $\delta$ can you choose such that $f(m)=f(x)$ for all $x \in (m-\delta, m+\delta) \cap \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What are the open subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3):

Let's take the definition that a function is continuous if all pre-images of open sets are open. Now $\mathbb Z$ has the discrete topology, and therefore *all* its subsets are open, including the pre-images of open sets under $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Fix any $\epsilon$ you wish. Setting $\delta=1/2$ insures that $|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, since if $|x-y|<1/2$ means that $f(x)=f(y)$, since there is only one point in a radius of 1/2 on the integer lattice.

Might also be worth looking up the open preimage definition of continuity and trying to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m\in \Bbb Z$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Set $\delta = 1$. Show that for all $n$, $\lvert n - m\rvert < \delta$ implies $\lvert f(n) - f(m) \rvert < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take the Weierstrass' $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ criterion. If $f:E\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0 \in E$, then $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x \in E \left( \left| x - x_0\right| < \delta \to \left| f(x) - f(x_0)\right| < \varepsilon \right)$$ Now Let $E := \mathbb{Z}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, $x_0 \in E$ be fixed. Taking $\delta := 1$, we get, that the only point which fulfills $\left| x - x_0\right| < \delta$ is $x_0$ itself, but then trivially $$\left| f(x_0) - f(x_0)\right| = 0 < \varepsilon$$ holds. Since $x_0 \in E$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous on $E$.

Comment: I think you want an epsilon in that last line

Comment: For sure, thanks.